# Syntax error near unexpected token ` | '

Tags: linux, bash, grep, scripting

I keep getting this error

```
line 3: Syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

This is the script at the moment:

```
for filename in $(ls $1) | grep -v ".old"
do
    mv "$1/$filename" "$1/$filename.old"
done
```

Any fixes?

Comment: `for` <variable> `in` <values> `;` `do` [ <command> `;` ]... `done` You probably wanted to write `"$(ls "$1" | grep -v '.old')"`. But then *you should never use the output of `ls` in a script*; it's for human consumption only.

Answer (score 4):

```
for filename in "$1"/*; do
    if [ -f "$filename" ] &&
       [ "${filename%.old}" = "$filename" ]
    then
        mv -- "$filename" "$filename.old"
    fi
done
```

Use `grep` for text, and use the output of `ls` for reading with your eyes, never as input to a program.

The error that you get is due to a syntax error in your code.  The syntax of a `for` loop (to loop over a number of words) is

```
for variable in word-list; do ...; done
```

The code at the top will loop over all regular files in the directory given in `$1` and give them an `.old` filename suffix if they don't already have it.  The two tests tests whether `$filename` refers to a regular file (or a symbolic link to one), and whether `$filename`, when removing `.old` from the end of its value, remains the same (i.e. whether it already has the suffix or not).

Another way of doing more or less the same thing is with `find`:

```
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name '*.old' -exec mv {} {}.old ';'
```

Note that both solutions would overwrite any already existing `.old` file if there is a corresponding filename without the `.old` suffix.  If there was a *directory* with an `.old` suffix under `$1`, the file would be put into that directory instead of being renamed.

The difference between the `find` solution and the shell loop is that the `find` solution would also care about hidden names, and that the shell loop would rename symbolic links to regular files.

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially admitted that this is a homework assignment
and not related to real life. 
As has been written in comments, your teacher probably wants you to do

```
for filename in $(ls "$1" | grep -v '\.old$')
```

If your teacher is extremely <s>stupid</s> unenlightened,
they may prefer that you leave out the quotes, the `\` and the `$`. 
Please introduce your teacher to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com). 
But, if your teacher can't or won't learn how to do things correctly,
then do the homework the way they want.

Then immediately forget it, because it's flawed.

---

Here's a variation on [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/486649/80216#486650)
that might be a little bit easier to read. 
(I added error checking because that's **the right thing to do**™.)

```
if [ "$1" = "" ]
then
    printf 'Usage:  %s <directory-name>\n' "$0"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d "$1" ]
then
    printf 'Error: %s is not a directory.\n' "$1"
    exit 2
fi
for filename in "$1"/*
do
    case "$filename" in
       (*.old)                  # Skip
        ;;
       (*)
        mv -- "$filename" "$filename.old"
    esac
done
```

You might also want to

- handle the case where `$1` is a directory, but either

  - you don't have full permission to it, or
  - it is empty.
- ask whether you are supposed to rename directories,
  symbolic links, and other things.

Answer (score 1):

With bash and [extended file expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in !(*.old); do ...
```